# Swift: Creating a repeating local notification between a set time each day

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, localnotification

I am trying to create a repeating local notification that will notify the user every hour between a set time every week day (e.g. 9-5 monday-friday) but after searching cant find any documentation on how to implement this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UILocalNotification is supposed to repeat every weekday, but fires on weekends as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855147/uilocalnotification-is-supposed-to-repeat-every-weekday-but-fires-on-weekends-a)

Comment: Is there a swift version/explaination of this thread?

Answer (score 0):

If you want only 5/7 it can be a problem.
When you schedule a local notification you can also set a calendar unit as `-repeatInterval` property. This is cool because there is an per-app limit (maybe 64) of maximum number of notification that you can schedule, thus creating one you can fire it each day at the same time.
If you need to create a different kind of repetition  is easy to reach that limit, to avoid that you can recreate further notifications each time the user open the app, or if you implement interactive notifications, each time the user interact with one.
Or but I've never tried you can create a notification for each day of the week `NSWeekCalendarUnit`(except sat and sun) an set the repetition to weekday for each, in this way you will only spend 5 notifications, for infinite repetition.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to make the notifications only fire between a certain time period each day? e.g. 9am - 5pm

Comment: As far as I know the answer is no.. just a specific time