# Local notifications firing immediately instead of when they are scheduled

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I've been trying to schedule local notifications by weekday, but they seem to be firing immediately  instead of when I schedule them. This is my code in AppDelegate in `didFinishLaunchingWithOption`s:

```
application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Alert, categories: nil))
        var notification = UILocalNotification()
        var components = NSDateComponents()
        var calendar = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
        components.weekday = 5
        components.hour = 9
        components.minute = 24
        notification.alertBody = "Notification test"
        notification.fireDate = calendar?.dateFromComponents(components)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

Any clues on why it might not be working?

Comment: Print your fire date and you'll see.

Comment: Well, printing the components gives me a proper result (the one I defined), but the fireDate gives me 0001-01-01 10:00:45 +0000. Does dateFromComponents not work the way I think it does?

Comment: Yes exactly. It just sets the given components on an empty date. Also you want to set `day` not `weekday`.

Comment: Oh, I see. I set weekday cause I wanted it go off at a certain day of the week, in this case thursday. Is that not the proper way to do it?

Comment: No, read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9855208/771231

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still have some doubts about what I have to do. So I should set, for example, a date for a random thursday and just have it repeat every week at one week intervals? Is that the proper way to do it?

Comment: You still haven't accepted any answers. Need some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned, make sure to specify the `year` and `month` properties of the `components` object.

```
components.year = 2016
components.month = 6
```

Part of the current fire date of your code is the following:

```
0001-01-01
```

Which means the notification will be fired at year "1" in January, not in 2016.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `notification.fireDate  = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5];`

Answer (score 1):

Try to set a year/month because it is created from 01/01/1970, so the date is in the past => immediate trigger